# java.lang.NullPointerException in File creation error

Tags: android, file, fileoutputstream, mediarecorder

I am trying to save output audio file in a separate new folder but when I try to start the app it crashes :

The code of my file creation is as follows:

In **onCreate()** aof mainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
          stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
          record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


         stop.setEnabled(false);
          play.setEnabled(false);

          final File path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                (
                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Utkarshrecord/"
                );

            // Make sure the sound directory exists.
            if(!path.exists())
            {
                path.mkdirs();
            }

           try {
               file.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", path);

            myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
            myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There are three buttons for **record** **stop** and **play**:

code for **record**:

```
record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                   myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                   myAudioRecorder.start();
                }

                catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
          });
```

code for **stop**:

```
 stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
                try{
                     myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder  = null;




                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
             }
          });
```

the error is as follows:

```
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sensorlist/com.example.sensorlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at com.example.sensorlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
10-05 14:44:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(31147):    ... 11 more
```

what should I do to remove it ?

Comment: what you set in outputFile, please mention here.

Comment: Which line is line 64 in MainActivity.java? and what did you assign to outputFile?

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere else, If you have any Fragments that are attached to the Activity, then check their `onCreate()` method where they are possibly accessing a null object reference.

Comment: 'path.mkdirs();' Start checking the return value as it might fail. if it returns false then do not continue with your code. instead display a toast and return.

Comment: And there seems to be strange stuff in your saving method: You open a file, then an fileoutputstream, you use the audiorecorder with the file, but never use the fileoutputstream, but to close it. There seems to be some profound misunderstanding here.

Comment: Even after solving this Null reference issue, you'll get app crash, you are recording a audio file but saving it with .3GP(video) format. invalid file extension.

Comment: @deejay Why would a different extension cause problems? I cannot imagine. And when would that app crash? At which action?

Comment: null there @kalpanac

Comment: I am using fileoutputstream to create folder @KaiMattern

Comment: null? what value u assigned there.

Comment: null to outputFile ! @kalpanac

Comment: it should not be null, please refere examples first- http://www.javatpoint.com/android-mediarecorder-example

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); here you are passing null. It should not be null, Here file object will be come.

Comment: I am using that example only just not including  `addRecordingToMediaLibrary();` @kalpanac

Comment: I have edited my code ! @kalpanac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For there are some mistakes which u have done which are very silly !

**Mistake 1:**

```
file.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", path);
```

For `static` ref it should be

```
File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", path);
```

and it should be stored it in your **file**  which is `null` till now !

2nd Mistake :

in Play button :
change it to

```
 m.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: thanx @utkarshdubey